# Ajax wont retrieve the file from php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hi guys this script was working fine when I add a console.log but as soon as I replaced the console.log with the $.ajax() function it wont give me the result back from the php file the ajax function I used was working from my other projects but I cant seem to find out why it wont work on this snippet

Here is my js code :

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#qs").find(".chs").each(function(i,obj){
             $(this).addClass("chs"+i);

             $(".chs"+i).on("click",function(){
                var s = $(this).data("lvs"),carrier= {"vars":s};

            $.ajax({
               url: aScript.php,
               type: "POST",
               data: carrier,
               dataType: "json"
                    success: function(data) { 
                        console.log(data) }
                });
            });
        });

  });
```

my php file looks like this

```
<?php
$json = $_POST['carrier'];
$data = json_decode($json);
$d = $data->vars;
echo $d;
?>
<input type="hidden" id="ss" value="<?=$d?>" />
```

can someone review this file for me cause I cant seem to find whats wrong please help me find out whats wrong with this script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the filename inside quotes, as it is a string variable

```
$.ajax({
               url: 'aScript.php',
               type: "POST",
               data: carrier,
               dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) { 
                        console.log(data) }
                });
            });
```

Comment: hi I tried this snippet but it wont still fetch the php file. what gives?

Comment: are you sure the aScript.php file sits in the right place?

Comment: oh silly me your missing `,` on dataType but it works now thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There  are some issues with your code

1. in this line `url: aScript.php,` the url string is not quoted, it should be `url: 'aScript.php',`
2. you set `dataType: "json"` but `aScript.php` returns html instead of json, remove that line
3. the data you're passing is not json, it will be serialized into key=value pairs and you'll be able to access it via `$d = $_POST['vars'];`